# Initializing complicated object

Tags: c#, class, initialization

EDIT: MAIN QUESTION - what will be the best way to initialize very nested object I can add anything to classes I can't change them.

In my project I have very complicated object to initialize, and in the future I will have to initialize above 100 different instances of those. I would like to ask you what will be the best way to partialy initialize them because I will never need full initialized.

```
public class PassivePowerUp
{
    public string name = "";               //powerup name to display
    public string description = "";        //description to display at runtime
    public Image icon = null;             //icon sprite
    public Sprite defaultSprite = null;    //icon sprite name on unlock
    public Sprite enabledSprite = null;    //icon sprite name on purchase
    public Image onEnabledIcon = null;    //additional sprite to show on purchase
    public bool locked = false;            //whether this powerup is locked (requirements)
    public bool enabled = false;           //whether the user bought this powerup
    public float[] cost;
    public PassiveTowerPowerUp towerProperties;
    public PassiveEnemyPowerUp enemyProperties;
    public PassivePlayerPowerUp playerProperties;
.
.
.
}
```

Where

```
public class PassivePlayerPowerUp
{
    public Health health;
    public Resources resources;

    //Game variables
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Health
    {
        public bool enabled;
        public float value;
        public float interval;
        public TDValue type;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Resources
    {
        public bool enabled;
        public float[] value;
        public float interval;
        public TDValue type;
        public CostType costType;
    }
}
```

The PassiveTowerPowerUp is even 3 times larger than PassivePlayerPowerUp.

Originaly those field were initialized in Unity editor so it was't a problem, but now I need to create and initialize them from code.

```
public PassiveTowerPowerUp towerProperties;
public PassiveEnemyPowerUp enemyProperties;
public PassivePlayerPowerUp playerProperties;
```

There will be only one of those initalized in instance

Comment: Do you have any constructors? Also, you are probably better off not having nested classes (this is just personal preference perhaps..)

Comment: I am not able to change architecture of those classes, they are built-in in game engine.
But I can add anything to them including constructors.

Comment: What game engine? I can't find any reference to unity having a `PassivePowerUp` class

Comment: Actually I am editing one game made in unity but many of other features depend on this class

Comment: Well adding constructors shouldn't affect other things.. (well maybe the default one would) but really you do need one. You should update your question with what restrictions you have because its unclear how to come around a solution..

Comment: If these classes are not sealed you should consider creating your own class and derive it from one of this classes...

Comment: Well as I said I can add anything I can't change nothing. I will probably add constructors to nested clasess that will at least partialy shorten the time of initialization.

Comment: Again, I can't see how you hope to achieve this without changing anything.. constructors won't shorten the time since you would need to initialize them in some way anyway. How were you planning on initiailizing these objects currently?

Comment: I was planing to use very big initialization list for  this object and initialize those fields I would need

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you do not need to initialize fields with the default values, this is done by the compiler automatically.

- Any reference type (`class`) field will be set to `null` automatically.
- Any value type (`struct`) field will be set to the default value.

For a complete reference, see [MSDN: Default Values Table (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

So you can change for example:

```
public Image onEnabledIcon = null;
public bool locked = false;
```

to:

```
public Image onEnabledIcon;
public bool locked;
```

For setting other values, I would either hardcode them or implement a loading mechanism to get the values from e.g. an XML file which contains the names and values of the fields.

Comment: Yes I didn't even notice that the fileds have initial values.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't have to set property with default value.

---

Default values

For `Numeric Types` => `(0)` Or equivalent value depending on type like (0.0)

For `Strings` and all `Reference Types`  => `null`

For `bool` => `false`

---

**Plus** You can initialize class member variables on declaration like :

```
  public string name = "DesiredValue";  
  public bool locked = true;
```

Or you can initialize them in the constructor like:

```
 public string name ;
 public bool locked ;

 public PassivePowerUp()
        {
              name = "DesiredValue";  
              locked = true;    
        }
```

**Finally** if the values may change from object to another then you can use `parameterized constructor` like

```
   public string name ;
   public bool locked ;

   public PassivePowerUp(string name , bool locked)
          {
                this.name = name;
                this.locked = locked;    
          }
```

Comment: Thanks mate for reply, but I know how I can initialize values I need an advise what will be the best strategy to Initialize so nested objects.

Comment: so, do you have any pattern for values?

Comment: what do you mean saying pattern ?
Object will always have only one of these initalized the rest will be default.
    public PassiveTowerPowerUp towerProperties;
    public PassiveEnemyPowerUp enemyProperties;
    public PassivePlayerPowerUp playerProperties;